# boot repair problem

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

After updating both win 10 and ubuntu, i can't access windows anymore because of

*alloc magic is broken at xxx*

from grub. Updating grub seems to fail to solve the problem. Boot repaor gives me this response

*The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)*

This is the link to the pastebin from boot repair

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZQppPwcFny/

How can i solve this?

Comment: Boot to a Windows install/repair disc and run chkdsk on your Windows partition.

Comment: Widnows updates may turn fast start up back on. Then grub will not boot Windows. You should be able to boot Windows from UEFI boot menu as long as you do not have BIOS/MBR type install. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: Thanks Oldfred, but I've already tried that and it doesn't work. I can't boot to the repair partition either

Comment: I used ntfsfix on sda3 and 5 and only one of these messages is left. Typing fsck on /dev/sda1 gives Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt". Should i remove the dirty bit with the same command or is there another way?